# How to check in python if I'm in certain range of times of the day?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to check in python if the current time is between two endpoints (say, 8:30 a.m. and 3:00 p.m.), irrespective of the actual date. As in, I don't care what the full date is; just the hour. When I created `datetime` objects using `strptime` to specify a time, it threw in a dummy date (I think the year 1900?) which is not what I want. I could use a clumsy boolean expression like `(hour == 8 and minute >= 30) or (9 <= hour < 15)` but that doesn't seem very elegant. What's the easiest and most pythonic way to accomplish this?

Extending a bit further, what I'd really like is something that will tell me if it's between that range of hours, and that it's a weekday. Of course I can just use `0 <= weekday() <= 4` to hack this, but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`datetime` objects have a method called `time()` which returns a `time` object (with no date information). You can then compare the `time` objects using the normal `<` or `>` operators.

```
import datetime
import time
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().time() # Throw away the date information
time.sleep(1)
print (datetime.datetime.now().time() > timestamp) # >>> True (unless you ran this one second before midnight!)

# Or check if a time is between two other times
start = datetime.time(8, 30)
end = datetime.time(15)
print (start <= timestamp <= end) # >>> depends on what time it is
```

---

If you also want to check for weekdays, the code you suggest is probably the most effective way to go about it, but in that case you probably don't want to throw out the original `datetime` object.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if 0 <= now.weekday() <= 4:
    print ("It's a weekday!")
print (start <= now.time() <= end) # with start & end defined as above
```

Comment: Yes, but that factors in the date, which is what I want to ignore. It also doesn't test for hours of the day. What I want is, running the code at 12:00 noon should always return True, and running it at 18:00 should always return False, regardless of what day it is.

Edit: your edit addressed that. Or maybe it was already correct. Thanks!

Comment: @limp_chimp This completely ignores the day, and only compares the `time` objects. I added an extra piece to the example to show a real test of the current time against fixed endpoints.

Comment: See my code for a complete example.  `.time()` throws away the date part of a `datetime`, leaving only the time part.

Comment: Just comparing start < time < end ? end_time doesn't need to be always greater, For example if the user wants to check between 10pm to midnight 1:30 am, How about considering cross over logic?

Comment: @nehemiahjacob Crossing over into another day is explicitly not part of the OP's question, so to include that logic would introduce unnecessary complexity. The only reasonable way to compare times "irrespective of the actual date" is to make the assumption that all given times occur on the same (arbitrary) date. If you can't make that assumption, you can't say anything meaningful about the relationship between date-free timestamps.

Comment: Makes sense, Yet in a way SO is often used it serves as repo of questions with matching title, hence it is worth mentioning. I arrived a quick logic while having to filter out list of dates in range. Take two sets A = {set of all times greater than start_time}, B={Set of all dates less than end_time}. Now if start_time < end_time the answer is A.intersection(B) else A.union(B).

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
if 0 <= now.weekday() <= 4:
    print "it's a weekday"
    if time(8, 30) <= now.time() <= time(15):
        print "and it's in range"
```

Comment: Could?  Sure.  If you're confused by something, ask - looks self-explanatory to me ;-), and the OP demonstrated he had a reasonable (if incomplete) working knowledge of datetime functionality.

Comment: Just asking because this showed up in the VLQ queue, and my standard procedure for code-only answers in the queue is to leave that comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 19, 3, 39, 38, 459765)
>>> 0 <= now.weekday() <= 4
True
>>> datetime.time(hour=8, minute=30) <= now.time() <= datetime.time(hour=15)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are getting your start and end time, but if you are limiting it to a single day, then be sure that the start time comes before the end time. If you had, for example, start time = 1800 and end time = 1200, you won't find any time in between on that day.